# Remove specified text from a variable using JQuery

Tags: jquery, text

I have a variable named `position` where I want to remove some of its text. The exact text I want to remove is contained within the variable `title`.

```
var title = $(currentLi).find('img').attr('alt');

var position = $(currentLi).find('span').text();
```

So just to clarify, I am creating a variable named `position` which contained text, I want to remove all the text that matches the text within the variable `title`.

Thanks for anyones help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
position = position.replace(title, "");
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
var title = $(currentLi).find('img').attr('alt');
var span = $(currentLi).find('span');
var replaced = span.text().replace(title, '');
span.text(replaced);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have made a jsfiddle for you that does the work.
Try to use `.replace();`

http://jsfiddle.net/P5tb8/

Answer (score 2):

Just use javascript replace.  Just add this after your existing code and believe it should return what is in the position variable minus what you have in title.

```
position = position.replace(title, "");
```